# Dismissing modal view makes main view rotate

Tags: objective-c

I have a main view that I rotate to landscape using

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(-0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
```

It works great. The problem is that this view can call a modal view, and when I dismiss the modal view the main view returns to portrait. Any ideas why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you overriding `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your main view and returning `YES` for any orientation? If not, your main view thinks that it can only support portrait mode, and will autorotate back to portrait whenever it comes to the front.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Great, that worked, but it is presenting a whole new set of issues.  I have a tool bar on the main view that now moves to the right when the modal view is dismissed.